# error during unit testing

Tags: java, jsf, powermock

I have a problem when compiling unit tests. I am getting the following error message.

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:143)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1935)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getCallbacksSetter(Enhancer.java:630)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.isEnhanced(Enhancer.java:604)
at org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl.isProxy(ProxyFrameworkImpl.java:29)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getUnmockedType(WhiteboxImpl.java:1783)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getConstructor(WhiteboxImpl.java:248)
at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.newInstanceCall(MockGateway.java:192)
at br.gov.dataprev.siaci.web.ConsultaProcessosTest.setUp(ConsultaProcessosTest.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:129)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:93)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:112)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:73)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

This error happens when I'm using PowerMock. Has anyone encountered this problem?

This does not occur at a specific point code. Occurs when I compile the test class. This is my test class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(BeanUtil.class)
public class ConsultaProcessosTest {

    private ConsultaProcessos consulta;

    private ServicoConsultaProcessos mockServicoConsulta;

    private Acordo acordo;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        consulta = new ConsultaProcessos();
        mockServicoConsulta = createMock(ServicoConsultaProcessos.class);
        consulta.setServicoConsultaProcessos(mockServicoConsulta);
        acordo = Util.criarAcordoComDadosMinimos("1");
        consulta.setAcordo(acordo);
    }

    @Test
    public void consultaComResultadosDeveIrParaPaginaDeResultados() throws Exception {
        List<ProcessoTO> resultadoConsulta = new ArrayList<ProcessoTO>();
        resultadoConsulta.add(new ProcessoTO());

        ParametrosConsultaProcessos parametrosConsultaProcessos = consulta.obterParametrosConsultaProcessos();
        expect(mockServicoConsulta.consultarProcessos(parametrosConsultaProcessos)).andReturn(resultadoConsulta);
        replay(mockServicoConsulta);

        PowerMock.mockStatic(BeanUtil.class);
        EasyMock.expect(BeanUtil.salvarValorRequisicao("resultado", resultadoConsulta)).andReturn(resultadoConsulta);
        PowerMock.replay(BeanUtil.class);

        String resultado = consulta.consultarProcessos(parametrosConsultaProcessos);
        String resultadoEsperado = "/pages/consulta/resultadoConsultaProcessos.xhtml";
        assertEquals(resultadoEsperado, resultado);

        verify(mockServicoConsulta);
        PowerMock.verify(BeanUtil.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and point the line where its throwing thie exception?

Comment: This error basically means that the implementation for the specified API class is missing in the runtime classpath. In other words, the error means that you've the JSF API, but not the JSF impl. Not sure how that relates to PowerMock and how/what it all expects, so I'm merely posting this as a comment, not as an answer, but it should give you a clue as to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out this one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Replace with the following dependencie:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
 <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
 <version>2.5</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

(if you are working with other app servers other than GlassFish, 
you might also need this one)

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
 <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

reference: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?57108-ClassFormatError-Absent-Code-attribute